# Does this Covetous Shen quote have a deeper meaning?

Tags: diablo-iii

After you rescue Covetous Shen from the water way in Act 2, he's pretty chatty. He talks about the architecture at one point stating, "You could walk all the way around the world and never see its like."

Immediately following, he says something very curious, "Except for this part. I've seen this somewhere before."

[image]

How intriguing. Is Covetous Shen hinting at something in particular? Could it be a nod at a previous Diablo game? Basically, should the player have any idea what he's talking about?

Comment: I think he's playing the part of a senile old man.  As in, "I've been walking in circles, so I've seen this before."

Comment: It's also possible he's breaking the fourth wall a bit - considering you'll take him through four difficulties, he *has* seen that before.

Comment: Does this ***question*** have a 'deeper' meaning, seeing as he asks that in the underground sewers? >_>

Answer (score 6):

> "Except for this part. I've seen this somewhere before."

This is a hint at the fact that some of the models in the dungeons are reused.  Blizzard is poking fun at themselves here.

The easiest example case is the [underbridge](http://www.diablowiki.com/The_Underbridge) zone in act 3 (random side dungeon sometimes accessible from Rakkis Crossing), you'll often see that exact shape appear in the Keep (somewhere between level 1-3)

Comment: has anyone at Blizzard actually owned up to this?

Comment: @spugsley no, but Blizzard rarely owes up to anything

Comment: I always thought it was more of a reference to how you play the campaign over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a throwback to Big Trouble In Little China where the actor was in the sewers near the end of the movie.

Comment: Do you have proof of some kind? Just curious where you found the information :) Add it to your answer and I'll gladly accept

Answer (score 0):

In reference to architecture, I thought he might be talking about those bearded faces in the sewers you meet him in.  They look almost exactly like the face from Harry Potter: Chamber of Secrets that is in the chamber if you've ever seen the movie.